# Is this well written?: for society isn’t normal for a person to remarry

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, word-order

I'm not an english speaker but that sentence sounds like wrong to me, I don't know why I think is because "for society" isn't well placed there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the position of "for society" but the absence of a grammatical subject. What is the subject of "isn't"?

We need a dummy "it" to function as an anticipatory subject of the real subject that is extraposed: "for a person to remarry."

The correct sentence would then be:

- For society, **it** isn't normal for a person to remarry.

Comment: +1. And we could make the extraposed subject  the subject directly: *For a person to remarry isn't normal*.  Though I'm still not sure what OP means by "for society".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Definitely. However, I think you'll agree that for the sentence to be more balanced the more "normal" position would be for the subject to be extraposed. My assumption is that OP means to say that that is so "from the perspective/point of view of the community" (society will object to the idea of a person remarrying).

Comment: Using  dummy **it** highlights the most salient element, I think.  "It *isn't normal*, in this society, for a person to remarry".

Comment: But that is not to say that emphasis upon **isn't normal** is available only when the subject is extraposed: *In this society, for a person to remarry isn't normal.*   The final position is another hotspot for emphasis.